# Merging two data.frames with multiple rows for separate cases of same person

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I am experiencing a problem when merging two datasets, which I hope someone can help me with.

Here's some example data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,3),2),a=c("x","y","z",NA),b=c(10,20,30,NA))
#    id    a  b
#  1  1    x 10
#  2  1    y 20
#  3  1    z 30
#  4  2 <NA> NA

d2 <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,3)),a=c("x","y","z"),b=c(10,20,30),c=c("d","e","f"))
#   id a  b c
# 1  1 x 10 d
# 2  1 y 20 e
# 3  1 z 30 f
```

I want to merge the two datasets to get the following set:

```
#   id    a  b    c
# 1  1    x 10    d
# 2  1    y 20    e
# 3  1    z 30    f
# 4  2 <NA> NA <NA>
```

However when I use the merge function I get an unexpected (to me at least) result:

```
merge(d1,d2[,c("id","c")],all.x=TRUE,by="id")
#    id    a  b    c
# 1   1    x 10    d
# 2   1    x 10    e
# 3   1    x 10    f
# 4   1    y 20    d
# 5   1    y 20    e
# 6   1    y 20    f
# 7   1    z 30    d
# 8   1    z 30    e
# 9   1    z 30    f
# 10  2 <NA> NA <NA>
```

The problem probably lies in the fact that I have multiple rows with the same 'id' 
(each representing a separate case for the same person), however, 
I cannot seem to find out what I am doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `merge(d1, d2, all.x = TRUE, by = c("id", "a", "b"))`?

Comment: Yes that's it, I knew it was something simple as that but couldn't figure it out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidArenburg comments, you can do this with:

```
merge(d1, d2, all.x = TRUE, by = c("id", "a", "b"))
```